# Activity Recognition in Background using Flutter

Tags: flutter, background, activity-recognition

I want to implement activity recognition in background that means if user close the application even then it'll listening the activity recognition states whether it is in IN VEHICLE, STILL or in which state.

I already tried activity_recognition_flutter: ^4.2.0 package to implement this -> Everything is working fine except in background it is not working when I close the application.I want to implement it in Android & iOS both and my current focus is Android primarily.

Can anyone guide with his/her experience if he/she knows how to do it.
Thank you !

Comment: [flutter_background](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background) maybe this package is what you are searching for

Comment: No, We're not able to do that using flutter_background even with flutter_background_service as well.

Comment: @PiyushSinghal any update on this issue, facing same issue in my app.

Comment: using method channel it can achieve , but you should write platform specific code for each of the environment

Answer (score -1):

Have you try passing BLoC events to flutter background?
The idea is you can devine events in your BLoC and let flutter background do the job equals to what events it helds.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31337521)